# Azure Eventhub Python - OWNERSHIP_LOST

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

I've copy-pasted this script and it works well. I'm getting all the events from eventhub:

```
import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient

connection_str = '<< CONNECTION STRING FOR THE EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE >>'
consumer_group = '<< CONSUMER GROUP >>'
eventhub_name = '<< NAME OF THE EVENT HUB >>'
client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(connection_str, consumer_group, eventhub_name=eventhub_name)

logger = logging.getLogger("azure.eventhub")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

def on_event(partition_context, event):
    logger.info("Received event from partition {}".format(partition_context.partition_id))
    partition_context.update_checkpoint(event)

with client:
    client.receive(
        on_event=on_event, 
        starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
    )
    # receive events from specified partition:
    # client.receive(on_event=on_event, partition_id='0')
```

However, once I try to get any value from the events I get an OWNERSHIP_LOST exception and the script doesn't retrieve anythinig.

I've tried `event.body.KEY`, `event.KEY`, `json.loads(event)['body']['key']`, `json.loads(event)['key']`.
Whatever I try to to with `events` it raises OWNERSHIP_LOST.

Do you know a workaround or happen to know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Examining event should not throw that exception. Do you get exception from update_checkpoint(event) call?

Answer (score 0):

The OWNERSHIP_LOST can be caused by errors when receiving events, or errors in on_event.  Could you try event.body_as_json()['key']?

Answer (score 0):

The `EventData.body` returns `bytes or Generator[bytes]`.

You would need to deserialize these raw bytes into string/object in a proper manner before extracting the content in the way you want.

The `EventData` objects has two helpers methods `body_as_str` which tries to decode the raw bytes returning string and `body_as_json` which tries to decode the raw bytes into string to then try to load the string returning a json object.

Parsing the raw received bytes depends on the data you send, it would be helpful to debug if you could provide a sample data.